# Flutter onsetState method?

Tags: flutter

My flutter app uses different classes and needs to refresh and rebuild items, but the refresh is only called in initState, so it only refreshes at the start. Is there an overrideable function?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refresh();
  }

  void refresh() {
    question = new Question(_raw);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential candidates:

- `didUpdateWidget`. Which is called right before a state is `build` a second time. Whether it's from a `setState` or a parent update.
- `didChangeDependencies`. This one is specific to `InheritedWidget` and will be called only when one of the `InheritedWidget` you subscribed to changed.